# How to handle correctly asynchronous webhook request?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, asynchronous, stripe-payments

I have a doubt.
Consider this scenario where I am creating a payment Schema containing a charges[] which will be filled with stripe charges.

```
const paymentSchema = new Schema({
    //Some other fields
    charges: [Schema.Types.Mixed],
})
```

Now, when I create a subscription for the user, Stripe charges him as soon as the subscription is created. So where is the issue? inside my initial function, I am updating some `Payment` fields like this

```
foundPayment.status = 'billing';
```

Before calling `foundPayment.save()`

The issue arises when creating the subscription as I want to push the charge object sent by Stripe API inside the charges array for that same Payment model, meaning that I will be updating the same model in 2 different requests. I consider this is not a safe practice, therefore, any suggestions about how to solve this scenario?

Comment: Can you check if the model exists before making the second change? You can also look at [idempotency keys](https://stripe.com/docs/api/idempotent_requests?lang=node) as a way to filter out duplicate transactions, etc.

Comment: Just a long short, how about redesigning the model such that 
you would save a charge with your `payment` schema `id`, you could save the charge anytime without worrying about the racing condition, you would just query your `charge` by `paymentid` to populate the charges list?

Comment: After doing some research I found that mongoDb works on a first come first served model, so in theory this issue shouldn't be a problem at the moment of doing this operation. Also thanks for the idempotency keys tip, I will take a deeper look at it as it sounds like is going to be useful in a near future.
Thanks for your replies.